# Infinite loop issue, when qty becomes zero

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onepage-checkout, quote

I am getting the infinite loop issue in the below scenario :

1. Added product 1 into the cart.
2. Added product 2 into the cart.
3. Make the qty to 0 from the admin-end.
4. Click on the checkout button and at this point I am getting the infine loop issue.

I have checked and observed that my request is not even reaching the OnepageController index action. So, I am thinking there is some code in any event observer that is resulting in the infinite loop issue.
Also I have observed that there is some custom code to remove the item from cart, if there the minimum qty is not available.

I have checked and infinite loop issue appears on the line

```
$quote->loadActive($this->getQuoteId());
```

inside `getQuote()` function in `class Mage_Checkout_Model_Session`

`loadActive()` function inside class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` further calls `$this->_afterLoad();` which is creating issue.

How can I track and debug this issue? or if anyone faced any similar issue earlier and has some knowledge to share.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your extensions one-by-one? Doing so will likely help you to eliminate the source of the issue.

Comment: @JosephLeedy Yes, but there is no much customization that disabling custom extension sometimes resulting in blank page or broken functionality and therefore increasing the effort instead of reducing. That's the reason I am asking if there is any method to debug the infinite loop issue.